# Remove Underline under Bullet List using TextConverter.importToFlow

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

In my application I display bullet list in text area using converting HTML string to TextFlow. It is working fine. But the problem is bullets are under lined if list item use underline style.

```
var htmlStr:String = '<FONT SIZE="13" COLOR="#333333"><UL><LI><FONT COLOR="#ff0000"><B><U>Item 1</U></B></FONT></LI><LI><FONT COLOR="#ff0000"><B><U>Item 2</U></B></FONT></LI></UL></FONT>';

textArea.textFlow = TextConverter.importToFlow(htmlStr, TextConverter.TEXT_FIELD_HTML_FORMAT);
```

Please help me to remove lines under bullets. I am using Flash Builder 4 and Flex SDK 4.9.1

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this case. Below my code

```
var htmlStr:String = '<FONT SIZE="13" COLOR="#333333"><UL><LI><FONT COLOR="#ff0000"><B><U>Item 1</U></B></FONT></LI><LI><FONT COLOR="#ff0000"><B><U>Item 2</U></B></FONT></LI></UL></FONT>';
var textFlow:TextFlow = TextConverter.importToFlow(htmlStr, TextConverter.TEXT_FIELD_HTML_FORMAT);
var arr:Array = textFlow.getElementsByTypeName("list");

if(arr && arr.length > 0)
{
    for each(var listElement:ListElement in arr)
    {
        listElement.listMarkerFormat.textDecoration = TextDecoration.NONE;
    }
}

textArea.textFlow = textFlow;
```